# How to get geometry in GeoJSON format using ST_GeomFromGeoJSON

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL/PostGIS. I have the following JSON format

```
"{'type': 'Polygon', 
'coordinates': 
[[[6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371], [6.69222819326484, 51.1329081193748], [6.69221180776184, 51.1329013203209], [6.69219149698336, 51.1329073049609],
  [6.69217949340067, 51.1329244260894], [6.69217956546811, 51.1329430447612], [6.69218526127669, 51.1329578171713], [6.692200130301, 51.1329606289999],
  [6.69220511560768, 51.1329581192089], [6.69221372090576, 51.1329518135339], [6.69222707128915, 51.132939215911], [6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371]]]}"
```

and I would like to apply the function `ST_GeomFromJSON()` as shown below in the code, but I am getting the error mentioned in the error section below.
How can I fix this?

Code:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
"{'type': 'Polygon', 
'coordinates': 
[[[6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371], [6.69222819326484, 51.1329081193748], [6.69221180776184, 51.1329013203209], [6.69219149698336, 51.1329073049609],
  [6.69217949340067, 51.1329244260894], [6.69217956546811, 51.1329430447612], [6.69218526127669, 51.1329578171713], [6.692200130301, 51.1329606289999],
  [6.69220511560768, 51.1329581192089], [6.69221372090576, 51.1329518135339], [6.69222707128915, 51.132939215911], [6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371]]]}")
```

Error:

```
NOTE: Identifier "{'type': 'polygon', 
    'coordinates': 
    [[[6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371], [6.69222819326484, 51.1329081193748], [6.69221180776184, 51.1329013203209], [6.69219149698336, 51.1329073049609],
      [6.69217949340067, 51.1329244260894], [6.69217956546811, 51.1329430447612], [6.69218526127669, 51.1329578171713], [6.692200130301, 51.1329606289999],
      [6.69220511560768, 51.1329581192089], [6.69221372090576, 51.1329518135339], [6.69222707128915, 51.132939215911], [6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371]]}" is changed to "{'type': 'polygon', 
    'coordinates': 
    [[[6.69223420722764, 51."]]}" will be shortened to "}".

ERROR: ERROR: Column "{'type': 'polygon', 
    'coordinates': 
    [[[6.69223420722764, 51."" does not exist.
LINE 2: "{'type': 'polygon',
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL assumes strings wrapped in `"` to be **object identifiers** - names for tables etc., while string literals should either be wrapped in `'`, or *dollar-quoted (`$$string$$`) to allow for easy escaping of `'` in the literal.

So your GeoJSON text should look like this:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
  '{"type": "Polygon", 
    "coordinates": [[[6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371], [6.69222819326484, 51.1329081193748], [6.69221180776184, 51.1329013203209], [6.69219149698336, 51.1329073049609],
  [6.69217949340067, 51.1329244260894], [6.69217956546811, 51.1329430447612], [6.69218526127669, 51.1329578171713], [6.692200130301, 51.1329606289999],
  [6.69220511560768, 51.1329581192089], [6.69221372090576, 51.1329518135339], [6.69222707128915, 51.132939215911], [6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371]]]}
  ')
```

Comment: fine  but the problem is that i do not enter the geojson manually it is encapsulated within an object.when i pass the geojson object i receive the above mentioned error.how can i modify the object itself in such way that to replace ' with " and " with '

Comment: @LetsamrIt if you don't want to fix the `toString()` of you code, you can consider Postgress `replace()` or the equivalent in whatever language you are using